# NDVI value from different download sources

Tags: ndvi, envi

I downloaded the Level 2 image of landsat-8 in GEE and calculated the NDVI value in ENVI. At the same time, the Level 1 image of the corresponding date was downloaded from the USGS, and the NDVI value was also calculated after atmospheric correction in ENVI. Consequently, the results of the two methods were found to be different. So I want to know which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Correct" in remote sensing is always a touchy subject. Correct as to what? Where does your ground truth measurement come from?

See for example this article specifically for NDVI:

> Moravec, D.; Komárek, J.; López-Cuervo Medina, S.; Molina, I. **Effect of Atmospheric Corrections on NDVI**: Intercomparability of Landsat 8, Sentinel-2, and UAV Sensors. Remote Sens. 2021, 13, 3550.
> https://doi.org/10.3390/rs13183550